# Is it true for finite morphism $f$ between integral projective schemes that $H^n(\mathcal{F})=H^n(f_* \mathcal{F})$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology

Let $f : X \to Y$ be a finite morphism between integral projective schemes of the same dimension over some field, and $\mathcal{F} \in \mathbf{Coh}(X)$. Is it true that $H^n(\mathcal{F})=H^n(f_*\mathcal{F})$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Yes that's true:* More generally, the property holds for *affine* morphisms, see e.g. [here](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01X8)

Comment: So, its true that if $U \subset Y$ affine then $f^{-1}(U) \subset X$ is affine too? (if $f$ is finite map)

Comment: Yes - are you using a definition of finiteness which doesn't incorporate this?

Comment: You're welcome :)